# How to insert into table has foreign key?

Tags: oracle

I have an access to remote view that i have to get information from.
What i wanna do is to insert those information into a table in my database,so that i created two tables: tableA has types and tableB has actual info with foreign key from tableA.
so i have view contains for example accounts info and those info have types ,i put those types in a separate table and each account in tableA has info about each type .

How can i wrap these tables together in a select (from the view) and insert into tableB based on tableA?
thank you.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the syntax for the Oracle INSERT statement when inserting multiple records using a SELECT statement is: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php